# Can't find a memory issue

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc

With testing of my code using valgrind I've recived the message:

```
*==18867== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==18867==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18867==    by 0x109609: readBoard (in /home/tima/Downloads/bd)
==18867==    by 0x109A06: main (in /home/tima/Downloads/bd)
==18867==*
```

I can't figure out what could cause this error, below you can find parts of the code that this message mentions:

```
// Struktura reprezentująca planszę
typedef struct board {
    int height; // wysokość planszy
    int width; // szerokość plansy
    int diamonds; // liczba diamentów na planszy
    point rf; // pozycja Rockfordu w tablicy field
    object** field; // mapa objektów planszy
    bool reachedExit; // true wtw, gdy Rockford opuścił planszę
} board;

// Oczyszczenie pamięci alokowanej dla planszy
void clearBoard(board* map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map->height; i++)
        free(map->field[i]);
    free(map->field);
}
// Inicjalizacja planszy
void initializeBoard(board* map, int height, int width) {
    map->height = height;
    map->width = width;
    if (map) {
        map->field = (object **) malloc(sizeof(object *) * (size_t) height);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            map->field[i] = (object *) malloc(sizeof(object) * (size_t) width);
    }
    map->diamonds = 0;
    map->reachedExit = false;
}
// Wczytanie planszy i zwracanie wskaźnika na nią
board* readBoard() {
    int height, width;
    scanf("%d %d", &height, &width);
    skipNewline(); // wczytujemy w pustośc symbol '\n'

    board* map = (board*) malloc(sizeof(board));
    initializeBoard(map, height, width);

    point pos;
    for (pos.y = 0; pos.y < height; pos.y++) {
        for (pos.x = 0; pos.x < width; pos.x++) {
            object input = (char) getchar();
            if (input == ROCKFORD) { // jeżeli wczytanym objektem jest rockford
                input = EMPTY; // to zamieniamy ten objekt na pustość
                map->rf = pos; // i zapisujemy pozycję Rockfordu
            }
            set(map, pos, input);
            map->diamonds += (input == DIAMOND);

            if (pos.x == width - 1) // jeżeli wczytany symbol jest ostatnim objektem wierszu planszy
                skipNewline(); // to wczytujemy w pustość symbol '\n'
        }
    }
    return map;
}


int main(void) {
    board* map = readBoard(); // Plansza, wczytana z wejścia
    move command = NOTHING; // Ruch do przemieszczenia Rockfordu

    // Dopóki nie wczytaliśmy koniec pliku
    while (isValid(command)) {
        stabilizeBoard(map); // stabilizujemy planszę przed ruchiem
        showBoard(map); // pokazujemy planszę
        while (readMove(&command)) { // wczytanie po jednemu ruchu dopóki nie spotkamy EOF lub '\n'
            if (!map->reachedExit) { // jeżeli Rockford nie opuścił planszę
                operateMove(map, command); // przemieszczenie Rockfordu według command
                stabilizeBoard(map); // stabilizujemy planszę po ruchu
            }
        }
    }

    clearBoard(map); // oczyszczenie pamięci
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to programming in C, therefore problem might be obvious. However I could where could this error come from for the long time and I will be thankful to the one, who can help me with it

Comment: You malloc() some memory but you never free() it.

Comment: I have it, edited main text

Comment: Compile with `-g` to have debugging info, it will show a line number.

Comment: You free()'d map->field but not the map itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Free' the memory associated with `map` as well after you are done releasing the memory with its fields.

```
free(map);
```

Unrelated but consider making `map` as global since it seems to be a single instance passed around the code too much.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure because I dont know much about C, but I think the problem is on this line:

board* map = (board*) malloc(sizeof(board));

I think the problem happens when C is trying to allocate object** from board on that line, but I don't know why, it seems correct on the paper to me.

Have you tried debugging step by step?